# How to pick file manually from a specified directory in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-packages

I used the `file_picker` package to pick files from phone external storage. I want to pick the file from a specific path. So instead of the going to external storage, I want it to go to a local path like `/data/data/com.example.edziban/cache/`. Then files can be picked from there only.

Comment: Please put all questions in your post.